# Bash auto-completion highlighting

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I'd like to know if it is possible to make bash auto-completion highlight the matched part of the auto-complete suggestion.

For example,
I am have directories with files such as these:

```
LSFJOB_647169535/ LSFJOB_647158534/
```

In this case, if I type `LSF` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then I get:

```
LSFJOB_6471
```

But then I have to focus hard to get which character should I type next.

I'd like bash to suggest me something like:

```
LSFJOB_647169535/ LSFJOB_647158534/
```

or

```
LSFJOB_647169535/ LSFJOB_647158534/
```

Do you know a way of doing it?

Answer (score 4):

That is a good question!

[Dennis Williamson](https://superuser.com/users/310/dennis-williamson) already answered it [there](https://superuser.com/a/251125/229645) (SuperUser).

So it turns out that there is a "ReadLine Variable" that does exactly that: `colored-completion-prefix`.

Sadly it's only available in **Bash v4.4** :c [Link to the diff](https://fossies.org/diffs/bash/4.3.46_vs_4.4/NEWS-diff.html)

You can check its value with `bind -v|grep color`

I tried to play with `compgen` but it appears that it strips colors away /:

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `colored-completion-prefix`, which requires Bash 4.4, you could add the older (Bash 4.0)

```
set completion-prefix-display-length 2
```

to your `~/.inputrc` (see [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-completion_002dprefix_002ddisplay_002dlength)). This replaces any common prefix longer than 2 characters with an ellipsis when showing the completions:

```
$ ls
LSFJOB_647158534  LSFJOB_647169535
$ cd LSFJOB_6471<tab>
...58534/ ...69535/
```